# Get-ChildItem but no folders (done this part) and only certain file types

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get a powershell script that moves all files from one folder (and it's subfolders) and puts them all in another folder. So far I've got this to work fine, but I also want it to only move a specific file type (.mp3).

*This is my first time playing round with powershell so its all a bit ahhh to me :D)

I've tried things like

```
-and (
$_.extension -eq ".mp3" )
```

under the Where-Object
This causes it to do exactly what it was doing before - it's copying over other non-.mp3's.

and

`-include "*.JPG"` before the `-Recurse` up the top part.
The powershell terminal opens, but nothing pops up on the screen and it closes instantly.

This is what i have working currently:

```
Get-ChildItem "E:\Downloads\*" -Recurse |
  Where-Object { 
  $_.PSIsContainer -eq $true

  } |
  Foreach-Object { robocopy $_.FullName "E:\Music\Compressed" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is this:

```
Get-ChildItem "E:\Downloads" -Recurse -File -Filter "*.mp3" | foreach { copy $_.FullName "E:\Music\Compressed" }
```

To explain a bit:

- `-File` this tells it to only return files
- `-Filter "*.mp3"` this tells it to only grab .mp3 files
- `copy` is fine, no need to robocopy

Comment: Thank you! Just a quick addon to keep my folders somewhat neat, after I take all the mp3's out of a subfolder is there a way to delete that specific one?

Comment: Yeah, just change `copy` to `move`

Comment: @Panomosh , I think he wants to copy the files with preserved access permissions , using robocopy tool

Comment: I doubt it @MahmoodShehab he is just looking to organise his folders!

Comment: @Panomosh , I used this task to complete moving files with permissions using this amazing tools , however I haven't experience this using Powershell, but its nice topic to explore.